# How to change default Android's Desktop application?

Tags: android

I hear that the Android's desktop is an application that I can change.
I'm searching for some information about how to do that.

Comment: Please specify what you mean with 'change'? Just change look&feel, theme, widgets, or entirely replace the default desktop app.

Comment: @Mathias entirely replace. I'll test the your approach and I back here to tell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you mean when you press the home button you want to have your app there instead of the default home screen? And do you mean on a non-rooted phone?

I use an intent filter for that, i.e. I want my activity to start on phone boot-up and be the default home screen.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

On a regular phone, the user will get an option to choose between your app and the default home screen though at first, although he can mark a checkbox then to always choose this app as the default screen then - but your app cannot force the user to do that.

Answer (score -1):

In the market you can search for Home Replacements. Once you install one and press the home button you will get a Choose Dialog, that let's you pick from the default Home and the newly installed one.

The current Home Screen that I use is [Launcher Pro](http://www.launcherpro.com).

Comment: But... that won't help too much. I guess, the dude want to know how to do it in his own application.