# How to clear default activity on shutdown of android device?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have created an Android application. I make it my default `Activity` on starting it.

My problem is that if I hard reboot or if the battery goes down, the device shuts down and my device keeps on starting that `Activity` and I am stuck into a boot loop.

How can I solve this problem?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by default ativity ?

Comment: default activity means the activity will be started on pressing the home button.

Comment: pressing the home button? or app icon?

Comment: I have set my activity as default activity by adding "HOME" as the intent filter. so it works as default activity for home button when my app is running

Comment: You probably mean _default Home Application_, not _Activity_. If so, take a look this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836215/android-change-default-home-application

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution is simple , make a BroadcastReceiver for a on Boot up , and a flag somewhere like ForceClosed set to TRUE, if application terminated without any error then set the flag to FALSE .

On receiving the Boot Broadcast , check if ForceClosed is TRUE , if yes , do watever you want , and then set it back to FALSE .