# Go back to launcher android programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I use the following code to set my app as the default program. Press the `home` key to go to my app...

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

It also boots with `DISABLE_KEYGUARD` directly into my app, without needing to unlock the phone.

How can I change back to the default launcher programmatically? Meaning, how can I go back to android home screen?

I tried using `System.exit(0)` however it doesn't work - it just goes back to my app instead of the android home screen.

---

The following is my code.
It goes back to my APP automatically.
Please tell any problem in the code.

**TesthomeActivity.java**

```
public class TesthomeActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnTouchListener(exitappTouchListener);
}
OnTouchListener exitappTouchListener= new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        }
        if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ){
            Intent i = new Intent();
              i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
              i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
              TesthomeActivity.this.startActivity(i); 
              finish(); 
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
}
```

**StartupReceiver.java**

```
public class StartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, TesthomeActivity.class);
    activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(activityIntent);
}

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.inno.testhome"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity android:name=".TesthomeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="StartupReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I believe adding finish(); will automatically take you back to where you started the application. If you have multiple activities, try to finish all of them in order to take you back to where you started.

Comment: The second answer is my code. Can anyone tell me any problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/is-quitting-an-application-frowned-upon)

Answer (score 2):

read this [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

or use  this

```
Intent i = new Intent();
  i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
  yourActivity.this.startActivity(i); 
  finish();
```

I think this will help you

Comment: It goes back to my APP automatically too...
However thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If your app is set as the default launcher, the Android system will automatically restart your app whenever it quits. It no longer has any concept of the original home screen - as far as the operating system is concerned, your app *is* the home screen now.

This is why you are unable to get back to the default launcher by quitting your app.
The only way to achieve the result you want is to [change the default launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3836215/663469).

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the `PackageManager` for the apps that respond to the Home intent.

You can then launch the correct one as you would start any other activity. Be sure to remove your app from the list before processing...

For useful info on that, I suggest @Commonsware's Launchalot sample app, which shows how to enumerate a list of apps that respond to a certain intent.

Check his code [on github here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot).