# Set default Launcher/Home programmatically in Android 4.X with System privileges

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I have an app with system privileges and I would like to set another app as the default Launcher/Home of the device. Is this possible in Android 4.X? I've only seen answers related to Android 2.2 or previous.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865367/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-default-launcher-app & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836215/android-change-default-home-application

Comment: Thanks for commenting but niether of both answers are useful on version 4.X of Android.