# GoLauncher and How did it get SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS permission?

Tags: android

For any custom Launcher/HomeScreen applications, the permission SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS is needed to set itself as the Default HomeScreen.

PackageManager::addPreferredActivity().

I'm aware of the StackOverflow threads on this issue [(example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836215/android-change-default-home-application) and that such a permission is only granted to apps signed with the OEM/Google certificates.

GoLauncher manages to set itself as Default Home Screen app automagically. They seem to have obtained the SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS permission too [(see here for permission list)](http://hoosier.store.aptoide.com/app/market/com.gau.go.launcherex/2/95630/GO%20Launcher%20EX#).

**How** ? is the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> GoLauncher manages to set itself as Default Home Screen app automagically.

Not on a Nexus S running Jelly Bean. After installing it, I get a chooser, just like any other home screen.

If you have an environment (post-Android 2.2) where GO Launcher Ex is doing this, please let me know so I can do more research.

> They seem to have obtained the SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS permission too

They do not have `SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS`. They are *asking* for `SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS`. You can ask for whatever you want; you will not get it.

Comment: Thanks. I could reproduce it in a 2.3.X Droid X2, but not on any of 2.3.x Note or 2.2.X Lg Ally. I wonder how the Go Launcher guys even get to do this, if you could give any pointers. My bad, since they had Set_preferred_applications in their permissions list i just assumed they might have got signed with a OEM cert.