# Signing with platform certificate revokes WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, apk

Following [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/Android-DevPhone-Updating/tree/browse_frm/month/2010-04?_done=/group/Android-DevPhone-Updating/browse_frm/month/2010-04?&&pli=1), I've signed a system app I'm working on using a specific device's proprietary platform certificates which I received from the manufacturer. I signed it as follows:

```
java -jar out/host/linux-x86/framework/signapk.jar \
     build/target/product/security/platform.x509.pem \
     build/target/product/security/platform.pk8 \
     Launcher-unsigned.apk \
     Launcher-unsigned.apk
zipalign -f 4 Launcher-signed.apk Launcher.apk
```

My launcher has various permissions:

```
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
[snip]
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissons" />
```

And I included in the manifest:

```
<manifest [...]
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" >
```

Where previously my app would succeed in writing the SD-card, but fail setting a preferred application ([my code similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12618533/154306)), it now no longer throws a SecurityException, but instead writing to the SD-card throws a FileNotFoundException with a message that permission was denied.

What could be happening that my app gets some protected permissions, but loses some others?

Comment: Look at logcat (from PackageManager iirc) while installation. It will tell you what permissions are not granted. Maybe there is some info.

Comment: Great suggestion. Pushing the platform signed app to `/system/app/` reveals nothing strange in logcat, I'm afraid. (Pushing the non-platform signed app shows "Not granting permission android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS" as would be expected.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ricardo Cerqueira](https://plus.google.com/115049428938715274412) (CyanogenMod developer) was so kind to respond to me privately via Google+:

> The system user, by design, can NOT write external storage. It's
>   actually the only user forbidden to do so.