# How to use customized screen instead of default start screen in Android?

Tags: android

I 'am making an enterprise app, the user should be able to use only those applications which i provide him. My idea is overriding the default start screen with my custom layout with the app icons, of only those apps which i provide to the user. I will disable home, menu back and search buttons in the starting screen. Even if the user presses home button he should be redirected to my custom screen which contains icons.

I have seen an application which has achieved this without rooting the device. [Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kytephone&hl=en) is the link for that app.

I just want to know how should i send the starting screen into background and my custom layout into foreground.

Answer (score 6):

Your app seems like a custom launcher (but with restrictives permissions).
So you can define your app as a launcher, to do that you can add this in the manifest :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Then you have to implements a method to get back to the real launcher.

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me. Take a look here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rn0UoFcv79c may be you can find what your looking for

Comment: I got a popup saying Complete action using Launcher or MyApplication(MyApplication is my app). If i select MyApplication with use by default for this action checkbox then i achieved my result, how to achieve this without the popup selection ?

Comment: The only way to do that is change the default choice for the launcher in the database. I think it needs a system permission, but i'm not sure.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide a link or an example. I tried a lot but i couldn't find any

Comment: yeah yeah, i'm looking for an example :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3836215/1720391 "only apps signed with the same signing key as signed the firmware can hold the SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS permission" So I suppose that you can't avoid the chooserActivity Widget in your case. Commons ware is right, it possible with a custom rom else the user keeps the choice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23560/discussion-between-anirudhmaddy-and-goo)

Answer (score 5):

> I 'am making an enterprise app, the user should be able to use only those applications which i provide him.

That needs to be a custom ROM.

> I just want to know how should i send the starting screen into background and my custom layout into foreground.

Make your app be the home screen. There is an SDK sample available that shows how to create a home screen.

Answer (score 2):

Q: How should I send the starting screen into background and my custom layout into foreground ?
A: Using BroadCastReceiver, you can achieve this through intent filter : android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
But, I am very curious to know, how did you override home key press functionality.

Comment: The initial default screen pops up first, then it is redirected to my app.

Comment: Try giving some delay while launching your app...But, this is the only solution you can find buddy... :)

Comment: I'm not sure that is the only solution... As example, the Google SetupWizard which pop during the first start,is declared as a launcher (so the home button redirect to it). You can see how declared your app as a launcher in my answer.