# Android Restricted Profile with different Launcher

Tags: android, android-source, android-4.3-jelly-bean, restricted-profiles

This is a bit of a science project; I'm trying to better understand launchers as well as the Android restricted profile system. I'm looking for a way to programmatically assign a different default launcher to a restricted profile than a non-restricted profile.

Basically I want to check if the profile is restricted and if so then set the default launcher for this profile to myRestrictedLauncher.apk instead of launcher2.apk.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the system or have root access when the restricted profile is created or updated, you can disable Launcher2 for the restricted profile in `/data/system/users/XX/package-restrictions.xml` where XX may be 10. Or you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836215/android-change-default-home-application) set the default handler for "home" intent.

On an unmodified system, you can enable an alternate launcher for the restricted user, but you sill cannot enforce its use, Eben if you disable the system launcher for this profile through GUI.

Comment: I'm looking into playing with this. What actually generates this package-restrictions.xml file?

Comment: The file is generated when the owner sets up a new user.